# Match between brakets that may contain other brakets

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex that matches brakets that may contain other brakets.

Example:

```
Match1(Match2())
```

I want the output to be:
Match1:
    $0 => 'Match1(Match2())' 
    $1 => 'Match1' 
    $2 => 'Match2()'
Match2:
    $0 => 'Match2()' 
    $1 => 'Match2' 
    $2 => ''

Is there a way to get it done, e.g. `\w+\(.*?\)`

Comment: What language or tool? are you dealing with nested brackets or the level of nesting is fixed?

Comment: Is a pattern like this valid? `Match3(abc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PCRE pattern `(([^()]+)\(((?R)?)\))` matches your input as follows:

- group 1: `Match1(Match2())`
- group 2: `Match1`
- group 3: `Match2()`

Note: Python's regex module, Perl, .NET, Ruby 2.0 and PHP support recursive patterns. Other popular languages like JavaScript, Ruby <1.9 and Java don't. See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mX2fG5/57

Comment: thanks it actully works but what does (?R) do?

Comment: You may change Python 3+ to Python `regex` module. Python 3 uses built-in `re` module that doesn't have any support for these features. Ruby supports on the other hand.

Comment: @MyDABD checkout the link I added to my answer which explains the details of `(?R)`